# Deploy automático de aplicativos Android e Ios

Tags: android, ios, mobile, ionic2, typescript

Alguém saberia informar se existe alguma ferramenta de deploy automático para aplicativos Android e Ios.

Alguma ferramenta onde eu possa dizer a ele qual a pasta do meu projeto, e quando eu mandar rodar o deploy, ele já gere a apk assinada e suba pras minhas contas na google play e apple store.

Desde Já agradeço.

Comment: Para iOS, o [Fastlane](https://fastlane.tools) pode te ajudar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Da uma olhada no fastlane, com ele você consegue fazer o continuous delivery dos seus projetos, é muito útil, principalmente se você tem vários colaboradores na equipe...

https://fastlane.tools/